# Visualizing Data time series using the zoo package

Tags: r, zoo

[image]

I am loading time series data using the `read.zoo` function. I noticed that when loading time series using `zoo` package it doesn't display as a data frame and when clicked on in displayed as shown in the picture.

One cannot discern what the data looks like from this. While data pulled using the `read.csv/read.table` are labeled as a data.frame and displayed in neat manner when clicked on. I know I can simply use the View(data) command but this is very cumbersome, I am sorry to be picky but it would be nice to simply click on the data and have it displayed with the appropriate columns and rows.

I also noticed that when I generate variables using the data-set that the new variables are never attached to the data-set in which they were created and therefore must use the `data=merge(data,newvariable)` command to combine it to the initial data.

Are there any techniques that can be employed to fix these two issues?

Comment: This is an issue with R - not RStudio. Have you read the help file for View? `?View`

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to use `read.table()` to read the data. Is there any advantage in using `read.zoo()` ?